# Returning an Array/Matrix in Excel VBA from a user defined function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel VBA and its been 5 years since I've done any VBA at all.  I've written a UDF to do a basic regression, but I can't get it to output an array of regressed values.  I select the range I want to output so and hit crtl+shift+enter, but it doesn't work.  I've tried a few different things, but nothing does the trick.  Here is my latest attempt:

```
Function REGRESSMEDIAN(x As Range, y As Range) As Double

Dim slope As Double, intercept As Double, count As Integer

count = x.count

Dim lny() As Double, regression() As Double
ReDim lny(1 To count), regression(1 To count)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To count
    lny(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(y(i))
Next i


slope = Application.WorksheetFunction.slope(lny, x)
intercept = Application.WorksheetFunction.intercept(lny, x)

Dim j As Integer

For j = 1 To count
    regression(j) = Exp(slope * x(j) + intercept)
Next j

    REGRESSMEDIAN = regression

End Function
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The code doesn't run?

Comment: This version doesn't run, but I had a version that did.  My issue is that it won't output the array of regressed values.  Even when I had it outputting an array, every cell was just the first value in the array.

Comment: Try changing the return type of the Function to Variant. So Function REGRESSMEDIAN(x As Range, y As Range) As Variant

Answer (score 2):

This test function:

```
Function tester()
    tester = Array("a", "b", "c")
End Function
```

will work fine as a UDF *as long as your 3 output cells are in a row, not in a column*.  If they're in a column then you'll just see "a" in all 3 cells.

[image]

If you're trying to put the output in a column then this will work:

```
Function tester()
    tester = Application.Transpose(Array("a", "b", "c"))
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I changed the function type to variant and that gave me the first value in all columns.  The transpose fixed that, it seems like the obvious answer in hindsight, I just wasn't aware that Excel VBA stores arrays as a row by default.

Comment: I would not say it's "obvious" - just have to remember that Excel has a preference for putting things in rows...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Function REGRESSMEDIAN(x As Range, y As Range) As Double()
```

only putting the parentheses in the function declaration.

It will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).