# Array function (UDF) only sets first cell in a row

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, excel-udf

I need to output to multiple cells in a row from an UDF and I tried this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669306/90800

```vb
Function tester()
    tester = Array("a", "b", "c")
End Function
```

However, only the first cell contains "a".

Comment: If you do not have a version of Excel with dynamic arrays (2021 or 365), then you will have to array enter the formula into as many cells as required.

Comment: Either that or use something along the lines of `=INDEX(tester(),COLUMN(A1))`

Comment: @Rory what does "array enter" mean?

Comment: Select three cells in a row, type `=tester()` and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter not just Enter.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, the `INDEX` version did work. But this will call my function multiple times, right?

Comment: Yes it would, but given the probability you don't know how many elements are in the array it seem logical.